# Getting a Salesforce Process Builder process to fire multiple criteria?

Tags: process-builder

I have started to have a look at the Salesforce Process Builder. My aim was to replace 5 workflow rules that each fire based on different criteria with a single process

The challenge I found was in this statement "When criteria aren’t met,
the process skips the action group and evaluates the criteria for the next action group. **Remember that the process executes only one action group**" from the help pages

So as soon as the first criteria is met and the actions fire the process stops. Meaning criteria 2-5 in my scenario never get reached.

I presume I am missing something obvious here ?

I could probably create 5 separate processes to replace the 5 separate workflow rules, but I thought the point of the process builder was to avoid this and have a single instance where possible.

Any thoughts anyone ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The current process builder has some limitations indeed. The fact that 'the process executes only 1 action group' means that you can only combine workflow rules that have mutually exclusive outcomes.

If at any time e.g. 2 of the 5 rules need to trigger, and you want to have them in 1 Process, you'd need to combine that scenario into a separate branch of the Process, and also combine the outcomes in that Process branch. This means you will have quite some duplicate logic in the Process.

This means that, as it currently works (Spring '15), Process Builder is certainly not always a better solution than 'traditional' workflow rules!!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old but should be said that this is now possible with Process Builder. Once you hit some criteria that is satisfied an action group will execute. Now if you want to continue executing more criteria to traverse other paths you can do that by setting the end condition to `EVALUATE THE NEXT CRITERIA` like this,

[image: Next Criteria]

You can see here that this process will execute the Closed Won action group if an opportunity is marked as Closed Won but that it will also execute the Closed Won and High-Value action group if the opportunity is marked as Closed Won and the Total Price exceeds a certain value since the previous action group ended with `EVALUATE THE NEXT CRITERIA`.

Answer (score 0):

As of Summer '16, you can evaluate multiple action groups. To do this you need to make sure you don't check the advanced option in your criteria - *Do you want to execute the actions only when specified changes are made to the record?*

[image]

With this setting unchecked you will not be able to add scheduled actions but you can now define a new process group and then click on the **Stop** for the previous Action group and you now get a nifty new feature to **Evaluate the next criteria**.

[image]

Save it and you can now execute multiple Process groups but bear in mind that they do not have any scheduled actions associated with them. I did a little testing and it seems you might be able to add scheduled actions to the last one but not too sure. Might want to do some more testing on your own. Hope it helps!

Resources - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=process_next_criteria.htm&type=0